# Typescript error # 70006 with type reference to any

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a react project and I have typescript within the project. This is new to me so I am trying to figure out how to fix a type error within my componenet...

```
let dragStart = (e) => {
    let transferringData = e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
    let collectedData = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    setTimeout(() => {
        mainStore.closeWidgetToolbar();
        let userWidget = dashboardStore.userDashboards().value.widgets[collectedData];
        dashboardService.addWidget(userWidget);
        setLayout(dashboardService.getCurrentDashboard().tree);
    }, 200);
};
```

the error is

`src/components/widget-toolbar/WidgetTile.tsx:15:22 - error TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: You can define ```(e: any)``` or type appropriate for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "noImplicitAny": false // <-----
  },
  ...,
}
```

or define a type to `e`:

```
let dragStart = (e: any | unknown)
```

Comment: I used the second method and defined the variable. it worked.